# Minimizing a summation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, regression

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this problem. I've been looking through notes, and I think I missed this when my professor discussed this in class.

$$
\text{Consider the data}\\
i\: x_i\: y_i\\
1\:2\:1\\
2\:3\:2\\
3\:3\:3\\
4\:4\:6\\
5\:5\:5\\
\text{As discussed in class, compute the line } y=p(x)mx+b \text{ that minimizes}\\
F(m,b) = \sum_{i=0}^{5}(y_i-(mx_i+b))^2 \\
\text{You find that}\\
m=\text{____}\\
b=\text{____}\\
F(m,b)=\text{____}
$$

We've been working on maximizing and minimizing functions by both partial derivatives testing for critical points and using lagrange multipliers to find max and min values, but I have no idea what to do with this to get my initial equations to work with. Can someone give me some kind of hint or instructions on what to do?

Comment: At the minimum, the derivatives in m and b will vanish.

Comment: Look up least squares regression

Comment: This question is not informative. It is reduced to a kind of calculus level. If I was a student, I would first ask why do we take the square of the difference but not for example the 4th power?why do we subtract but not divide? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where it was in my notes. We went over it very briefly, so it was a small section. Here's what you need to do.

$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{m}} = \sum_{i=1}^{5}2(y_i-mx_i-b)*(-x_i)\\
= -2(\sum x_iy_i-m\sum x_i^2-b \sum 1) = 0\\
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{b}} = -2(\sum y_i -mx_i-b)\\
-2(\sum y_i -m\sum x_i-b\sum i) = 0\\
\text{now we do some algebraic manipulations}\\
m\sum x_i^2 + b\sum x_i = \sum x_iy_i\\
m\sum x_i+b\sum1=\sum y_i\\
\text{and now we can solve for parts of these equations}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{5} 1=5\\
\sum x_i = 17\\
\sum x_i^2 = 63\\
\sum y_i = 17 \\
\sum x_iy_i = 66\\
\text{We now get two equations with two variables we can solve for}\\
Eqn 1: 63m + 17b = 66\\
Eqn 2: 17m + 5b = 17\\
\text{Solve for b in Eqn 2 yields}\\
b = \frac{17}{5}(1-m)\\ \text{Plug into Eqn 1 and solve for m}\\
m = \frac{41}{26} \\
\text{Which makes b}\\
b = \frac{17}{5}-\frac{17*41}{5*26}
$$

For the final portion, $F(m,b)$ you just need to plug in all the values and do the addition.

Answer (score 2):

Let our best fit line be described as $mx + b$

We would hope that we could solve for $m$ and $b$ without any contradictions using the system of equations:

$\begin{cases} 2m+b = 1\\
3m + b = 2\\
3m + b = 3\\
4m + b = 6\\
5m + b = 5\end{cases}$

Which can be expressed as the following matrix equation:

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\3&1\\3&1\\4&1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m\\b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\6\\5\end{bmatrix}$

You will unfortunately find that this system is inconsistent and no exact solution can be found ($3m+b=2$ and $3m+b=3$ simultaneously is impossible).  However, a least squares fit can be found.  To do so, multiply on the left by the transpose of the first matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}2&3&3&4&5\\1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\\3&1\\4&1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m^*\\b^*\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2&3&3&4&5\\1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\6\\5\end{bmatrix}$

This system, in the form $A^TAx=A^Tb$, will be consistent and the solution (or solution set in the case of infinitely many solutions) will be the best fit line.  Solve the system either by row-reduction, or if $A^TA$ is invertible as $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$, or using your other favorite technique.

(Note: it is as mentioned possible for infinitely many possibilities to occur, in particular when $(A^TA)$ is non-invertible.)

In this case it will be invertible, so we take the easy route and complete the problem as:

$\begin{bmatrix}m^*\\b^*\end{bmatrix}=\left(\begin{bmatrix}2&3&3&4&5\\1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\3&1\\3&1\\4&1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}2&3&3&4&5\\1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\6\\5\end{bmatrix}$

$=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{26}&-\frac{17}{26}\\ -\frac{17}{26}&\frac{63}{26}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}66\\17\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{41}{26}\\-\frac{51}{26}\end{bmatrix}$

Giving us that our best fitting line will be of the form $\frac{41}{26}x-\frac{51}{26}$

---

Alternatively, approaching via another method, expand $F(m,b)$ and try to calculate its minimum value using derivatives.

$F(m,b)=(1-2m-b)^2 + (2-3m-b)^2 + (3-3m-b)^2 + (6-4m-b)^2 + (5-5m-b)^2$

$=5b^2+34bm-34b+63m^2-132m+75$

We try to calculate critical points where $F_{m}=F_{b}=0$, and test $D=F_{m,m}F_{b,b} - F_{m,b}^2$ to see if they are maximums, minimums, or saddle points.

$F_m = 34b + 126m - 132$

$F_b = 10b + 34m - 34$

Setting each equal to zero, we see that each forms a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and they are not parallel) and so there will be only one critical point.  Find the intersection of the line and verify that it is indeed a minimum.

These intersect at the point $m=\frac{41}{26}, b=-\frac{51}{26}$.  After some tedious arithmetic, we confirm that $D>0$ and $F_{mm}>0$, implying that this point is indeed a minimum for the multivariable function $F(m,b)$.

Giving us that our best fitting line will be of the form $\frac{41}{26}x-\frac{51}{26}$

---

(*double checked, both methods did in fact yield the same answer*)

Comment: @BCqrstoO indeed.  Both methods I exhibit result in the same answer as yours: $b=-\frac{51}{26}, m=\frac{41}{26}$.  The method using matrices is in my opinion the easiest to implement, but given the tools used in your solution, would not have been what you were taught.  The second solution I gave actually matches your solution, however I did my algebraic manipulations before taking derivatives, whereas you took derivatives before algebraic manipulation.  Note: $63m+17b=66$ is the same equation as $34b+136m-132=0$.  Similarly $17m+5b=17$ is the same as $10b+34m-34=0$.

Comment: @BCqrstoO Additional information on the matrix method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#The_general_problem), [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx6CfgKVIuE).  Typo in line above for the record., I meant to say $34b+\color{red}{126}m-132=0$.  Too late to edit.